# Ionic 3 - Page Navigation : Is it possible to declare a components section?

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation

I am trying to understand the Ionic 3 navigation and layouting system, which is still not clear to me. So my question is: Is it possible to put a page (ngx component) to a certain section of another page (see picture). As far as I know, the Navigation Manger (NavController) pushes or pops a page onto the Stack. But what I want, is to push a page to a certain segment of another page. For example the tabs-template uses this approach. The main objective for me, is to keep page components like (Header, Navigation) across multiple pages!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the boilerplate code from ionic then you can change the `app.html` and include there your header and navigation (footer).

Something like:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{currentPage.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-nav [root]="currentPage"></ion-nav>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="currentPage">
      <ion-segment-button [value]="home">
        Home
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button [value]="about">
        About
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button [value]="contact">
        Contact
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

You can see an actual running sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-single-header-and-footer?file=app/app.html

Comment: Ok thanx! This enables me a different approach for the equal problem. But I don't use the navController in this example? Hence, I have to create page animation/transitions by my self ?

Comment: How would you navigate without using `Nav component`? A dynamic component that will inject the page? If so then AFAIK you will be the one to create it. But ultimately, i really don't want to do something like that because the `Nav component` should be the one that handles the pages.

Comment: Thanx ... I found "ion-nav is the declarative component for a NavController" in the documentation... Helped me alot!